# Como resolver CORB mesmo adicionando Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Adicionei a instrução `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` em meu php, porém continuo vendo a o erro

> jquery.min.js:2 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin
>   response http://meusite.com with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

```
$("#formcontato").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false
    }).done(function(response){ 
      console.log(response);
        $("#server-results").html(response);
        $("#formcontato")[0].reset(); 
    });
});
```

Estou pesquisando a 3 dias e não consigo resolver, não é falta de esforço, só não consigo encontrar um conteúdo que realmente resolva meu problema.

Comment: o CORB é diferente do CORS, adicione o codigo da requisição em javascript na pergunta para que possa ser analizada também, segue um debate sobre esse item https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb

Comment: Obrigado, código javascript adicionado

Answer (score -1):

Retorne a resposta com o cabeçalho 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' Verifique no código abaixo a resposta do servidor PHP.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($phparray);
```

você pode está fazendo uma requisição JSONP e o servidor está respondendo JSON, coloca também o content-type no seu header, e ai seu navegador pode está recusando sua tratativa...